# How do I fix an issue with Disk Manager that is causing a Windows Boot Manager Error?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, disk-management

A user of my desktop erroneously clicked 'make drive active' on the C: drive in Disk Manager. This has caused a Windows Boot Manager Error when I try to restart the computer. Here is what I do not understand:

I have two drives, a C drive and an E drive. The C drive has the Windows 10 operating system so it should have already been active right? The E drive has no operating system, it is just for storage. In my BIOS, Boot priority only shows my C drive disk however when I click 'Boot Menu' I am able to see both disks. If I click the disk that is my E drive, the computer will boot just fine. How is this possible if the E drive has no OS? How do I fix this without losing all my files? Disk Manager looks how I would expect if things were working correctly but I am not very familiar with it so I could be wrong. Also the E drive has no new files written to it (for the last couple months) so there's no way it can actually be booting from E?

I tried using a USB loaded with Windows 10 installation media to enter the recovery terminal and execute `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixBoot`. The first executed successfully and the second I don't have access to for some reason even though I am the administrator.

The screenshots below describe the situation.
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some (most) of this kind of problem are easily resolved if using the recommended UEFI mode (and GPT) for any computer from 2012 or newer. Besides, using Legacy/MBR is new NVMe drives is really asking for trouble, one way or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, as you can see in Disk Management, "drive letters" belong to partitions, not to whole disks – "E:" isn't your whole HDD, "E:" is just one of the *two* partitions on that HDD. Second, similarly, the "active" flag is set for a specific partition only, again not to the whole disk.

So it doesn't matter whether E: has an OS in it or not, because it *isn't* the "E: drive" that you're booting from – it's the other "System Reserved" partition that does the job, and that is where your Windows Boot Manager happens to be located.

(In "legacy" boot mode that you're using Disk Management app cannot actually set a whole disk as active – there are no BIOS interfaces for changing the boot order – instead, what's being set is which partition *on each disk* should be active.

That is, first the BIOS selects a disk to boot from, and only then the disk's MBR looks for an active partition on that same disk. If it doesn't find any, it might return to the BIOS which then selects another disk and repeats. In your case, perhaps the BIOS *was* trying the M.2 module first, but it had no active partitions so the second disk i.e. the HDD ended up being booted from.)

Finally, note that all recent Windows versions create two partitions during installation – one small partition that contains *only* the Windows Boot Manager with its BCD, and a second large partition that contains Windows, your files, but does not actually have the Boot Manager in it. (In fact, EFI boot mode pretty much requires two partitions, but Windows does this even on legacy-BIOS systems to minimize the differences. Some computers do have just one partition, sometimes as a result of upgrading from WinXP, but as a general rule it is normal to have two.)

So in your case, you actually ended up with a split installation where the actual Windows OS partition is on the M.2 module, but the Windows Boot Manager partition is on the HDD. (This might have been an accident, maybe due to the HDD being 1st in the BIOS boot order, or it might have been deliberate.)

---

One possible way to resolve this might be to boot from a Windows install USB again, and this time run `bcdboot` to install the entire Windows Boot Manager into the C: partition. For example:

```
bcdboot C:\Windows /s C: /f BIOS
```

This will copy "fresh" Boot Manager files from C:\Windows\Somewhere into the proper place in the C: partition, for the BIOS (legacy) boot mode.

---

Personally, I would instead spend some more time to shrink/move the C: partition to make some space for a separate "System Reserved" partition – and then use `bcdboot` to install the Windows Boot Manager there instead.

Doing so would better match Microsoft's expectations of the "standard disk layout", and would also make it easier to convert the disk to GPT/UEFI boot process later as well. (I've seen a few motherboards where setting the firmware to UEFI-only and disabling legacy-boot support would shave several seconds off the boot process.)

(Although the current partition is 50 MB, Microsoft's recommendation is 100 MB. It's traditional, although not required, for the "System Reserved" partition to be the first/leftmost one, so GParted Live could be used to move C:\ to the right.)